Docker Playground displaying incorrect networking configuration for docker swarm
I am learning docker and using docker playground for that. However, earlier when I used the swarm set up on the playground or even performed swarm init myself, I was able to view all 5 default networks (including docker_gwbridge and ingress) on the manager and worker node.
However, now when I run - docker network ls, the manager node displays below response.

The docker_gwbridge is missing, but on performing ip a, I am able to view it.
But, I get the below response.

Also, on worker node, the response is as below, the ingress network is missing.

On manager node, if I run docker inspect ingress, the container ingress_sbox is also not visible.

A few months back, all the configurations used to be proper. Are there any recent changes in docker networking structure or is this issue specific to docker playground?
